# React Native - iOS is not recognizing Branch Links

Tags: ios, react-native, branch, branch.io, ios9.2

We are trying to analyze where the users come from with branch's getLatestReferringParams in React Native, however in iOS the params for ['+clicked_branch_link'] is always undefined when the actual sessions comes from a branch link, this problem is only happening with iOS (it's working with Android), and we have also tested trying to open this link via Chrome in the iPhone and it worked. I'm not completely sure if it's related to something going on with Safari or with the OS versions. Any guideline would be very welcome. Thanks Here is a small snippet of the code we are trying to implement

```
    const lastParams = await branch.getLatestReferringParams()
    const comesFromBranchLink = lastParams['+clicked_branch_link'] # Giving us undefined when it comes from a branch link
    const isAReferralLink = lastParams['~feature'] === 'referral'
```

Edit: We tested again and basically it doesn't recognize the branch link, only if it comes from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: this sounds like a possible configuration issue with Universal Links.

I see you have also submitted a ticket to our Integrations team, which is the quickest way to get a solution. I will make sure we follow up here with an update when the issue has been resolved!

Comment: Was there ever any feedback for this Alex? I was just facing a similiar thing.

Comment: @MichaelStokes unfortunately it looks like we never heard back from Guillermo on whether this was resolved, which is why I never posted an update! Could you [write in to our Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)? It'll be a lot easier for them to help triage the issue there.

Comment: Thanks very much, yes currently in communication regards :)